# Get selected text of a combo box using jQuery, by name of the combo box?

Tags: jquery, combobox

How Can I get selected text value from the combo box using jQuery.

I am having only "name" of combo box.

So, I want the text of selected item, using the **name** of combo box, not ID.

I am having ,

```
var selected_fld = ( $(this).attr('name') );
```

How can I proceed further ?

Answer (score 16):

```
$('select[name=nameOfTheBox]').val();
```

or

```
$('select[name=nameOfTheBox] option:selected').val();
```

will give you the value of the selected option

```
$('select[name=nameOfTheBox] option:selected').text();
```

will give you its text

Answer (score 9):

This can be done simply with the following to get the actual text value...

```
var value = $("[name='MyName'] option:selected").text();
```

or this to get the option 'value' attribute...

```
var value = $("[name='MyName']").val();
```

With the following html, the first will give you 'MyText', the second will give you 'MyValue'

```
<select name="MyName">
   <option value="MyValue" selected="selected">MyText</option>
</select>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mQSYh/)

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
<select name="name1">
      <option value="val1">val1</option>
      <option value = "val2">val2</option>
</select>

var text = $("select[name='name1'] option:selected").text();
```

Comment: the single quote after `selected` must be a double quote

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id ="myCombo">
   <option value="Play selected="selected">Here</option>
   <option value="Once">Again</option>
</select>

$('#myCombo option:selected').text();
```

This will return you "here"

```
$('myCombo option:selected').val();
```

This will return you "Play"

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#selectnumber').change(function(){
                alert('.val() = ' + $('#selectnumber').val() + '  AND  html() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').html() + '  AND .text() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').text());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <select id="selectnumber">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Click to See OutPut Screen]

Thanks... :)